# Javascript function reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, function, referenceerror

I am trying to call a Javascript function through a command button on my Rails app.

```js
function fetchpurchases() {
  var startDate = $('#histStart').val();
  var endDate = $('#histEnd').val();
  $('#histMainFrame').empty();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/transHistory/confirm?start_date=' + startDate + '&end_date=' + endDate,
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#mainContDiv').append('<img id=\'spinner\' src=\'/assets/spinner_green.gif\'>');
    },
    success: function(output) {
      $('#spinner').remove();
      $('#histMainFrame').html(output);
      $('#transPurTab').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        pageLength: 50,
        paging: true,
        stripeClasses: ['oddStrip','evenStrip']
      });
    }
  });
}
```

A button is defined with the onclick event calling the Javascript function.

```html
<div id="histToolbar">
  <div id="errorDiv"><p class="bigRedBright"></p></div>
  <table id="histTools">
    <tr>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="histStart" placeholder="Start Date..."></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="histEnd" placeholder="End Date..."></td>
        <td><button onclick="fetchHistory()" id="histSubmit">Submit</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="fetchpurchases()" id="deliverSubmit">Confirm Delivery</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I can navigate to the page I created by typing it manually into the browser. The MySQL query I wrote works correctly, but when I try to navigate using the button, I get `reference error: fetchpurchases is not defined`.

Additionally (may not be related), the function does not show up in the DOM window when I try to debug the error using Firebug.

Comment: Is `fetchpurchases` bound to the window? You could try attaching it to the window or to be better attach an `App` object to the window and place your functions in there to namespace them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like so

```
// Create a namespace for your code
var App = App || {};

(function() {
  App.fetchpurchases = function() {
    //Your code here
  };
})();
```

If you don't want to use JS or jQuery to bind the function to an event you can change your HTML to:

`<td><button onclick="App.fetchpurchases()" id="deliverSubmit" type="button">Confirm Delivery</button></td>`

Of course wherever you place that javascript needs to be added to `application.js` or loaded into the page manually.